# Rails - Best way to save "Given Answer" in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a quiz app with Ruby on Rails where I have a model "Answer". Now I need to save the answer a user gives for a question to the database, so I thought I'll make a model "GivenAnswer" and matching controller with these existing models as attributes:

- "User"
- "Question"
- "Answer"

I'm going to put all the logic for analyzing the given answers into the "GivenAnswers" controller, but am not sure how the db migration should look. Also, I would like to have indexes on "User" and "Question", since I'm going to frequently display "answers per user" and "answers per question". I generated this migration:

```
class CreateGivenAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :given_answers do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :question, foreign_key: true
      t.references :answer, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But I'm wondering if the table should be purely relational instead:

```
class CreateGivenAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :given_answers, id:false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :question, index: true
      t.belongs_to :answer
    end
  end
end
```

I'm a Rails beginner, so I'd be thankful for any pointers.

Comment: since your question is about db migration, better add the tag `rails-migrations`, if you are working with `rails5`also add `ruby-on-rails-5`

Comment: thanks for the tip :) @Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`belongs_to` is an alias for `references` so it makes no difference which of those you use.

Don't remove the id column in this case.

Any foreign key should also be an index.

I would do this:

```
class CreateGivenAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :given_answers, id:false do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :question, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :answer, index: true, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't think that you should relate `Answer` directly to `GivenAnswer`. It would make more sense to relate `Answer` to `Question`

Comment: Thank you @Toby, that makes sense. `Answer` is related to `Question` with a * to 1 relationship. Why do you say I shouldn't relate `Answer` to `GivenAnswer`?

Comment: Are you saying there is more than one answer for a question or more than one question for an answer? If `Answer` is related to `Question`, and `Question` related to `GivenAnswer` then `GivenAnswer` can access `Answer` through `Question`. If it is also given a direct reference to `Answer` then it leaves open the possibility for inconsistencies at the database level.

Comment: For example, what if the answers for a question changed, but the answers linked to the given answers for that question didn't get changed? So now the correct answer for question A has become X but the given answer objects on question A are saying the correct answer is still Y. Inconsistencies at the database level should be avoided at all costs because they will make your application un-maintainable in the long run.

Comment: I see your point @Toby. In my application each Question has multiple Answers (multiple choice question type quiz), but each Answer belongs only to one Question. So to avoid inconsistencies I originally thought about only including User and Answer as attributes in the GivenAnswer table. But since I will be showing given answers indexed by Question a lot, I thought it would be simpler to include the Question column as well, as long as I make sure that before a new GivenAnswer record is saved that the Question in the Question column and the one linked to the Answer object are the same.

Comment: As for consistency after the Answers for a given Question are saved: that is a good point, I had not yet thought about that. I'd still want the GivenAnswer to reference the old Answer object (since that is what the user picked), but could use a sort of soft delete, so the Answer controller does not overwrite old Answers when the quiz author changes something, but rather makes new records and flags the old ones as deleted (but still accessible by the GivenAnswer table).